# Does the Kinesis Input Plugin of LogStash Support Enhanced Fan-Out (EFO)?

Tags: logstash, amazon-kinesis

I'm currently designing a system that leverages Logstash for processing streaming data from Amazon Kinesis Data Streams and there are 4 logstash instances as consumers. I happen to find that there's such relevant plugin Kinesis Input Plugin. Before proceeding, I would like to confirm whether the plugin supports Enhanced Fan-Out (EFO).

I have reviewed the plugin documentation available at the GitHub repository, but I couldn't find explicit information regarding EFO compatibility.

```
1. Does the Kinesis input plugin currently support EFO?
2. If so, are there any specific configurations required to enable EFO within the plugin?
3. Are there any known limitations or considerations when using the plugin with EFO?
```

Thanks a lot